# How to recreate a webpage by its HTML with pictures

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I would like recreate a page by its HTML and make it available offline for me (https://infoc.eet.bme.hu/ea12/  , like eloads12.html) because the full content of the page is only available for 1-2 weeks every year. So far, I could only recreate the text of the page without the pictures but the pictures would be important too. Any help would be appreciated.

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    r=requests.get("https://infoc.eet.bme.hu/ea12/")
    print(r.content)
```

I have tried print(r.content) as well without any success. I do the recreation manually.

Comment: download the images (for eg. https://infoc.eet.bme.hu/ea12/teszt.png ) and save the images in the location where the html will be..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download the image and use it as your background or adding it as image tag. Be sure to save the image file in the same directory with your HTML file so you can access it easier. This will also make your HTML file useable offline since the images are stored on local machine.

Hope this helps =)